# iOS and salesforce API connection

Tags: ios, wsdl, salesforce

Hello I am new in WSDL salesforce API integration in iOS. And I got some WSDL to OBJC library files included into xcode project. And my first task is to go with app login screen. And as per android version we need to connect salesforce api with our app using :

```
ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
config.setUsername(username);
config.setPassword(password);
config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint);
config.setTraceMessage(true);
config.setPrettyPrintXml(true);

partnerConnection = Connector.newConnection(config);
```

And in the response received sessionID. and set to sessionHeader.

So I think, I need same thing in iOS version. So please guide me to access the salesforce webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet it to use a pre-existing SDK for Salesforce that is for iOS, rather than trying to map from some java/android code. Check out the [Salesforce iOS SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS) or [ZKSforce](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce)